# Is there a better way to do this join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table of my sales agents' sales, by quarter:

```
Agent          Quarter Sales
----------------------------
Alex Andersen  2011Q1    358
Alex Andersen  2011Q2    289
Alex Andersen  2011Q3     27
Alex Andersen  2011Q4   2965
Brian Blogg    2010Q3    277
Brian Blogg    2010Q4    123
Brian Blogg    2011Q1    783
Brian Blogg    2011Q2      0
Christy Cliff  2011Q2    777
Christy Cliff  2011Q3    273
Christy Cliff  2011Q4    111
Christy Cliff  2012Q1    901
```

What's the simplest, most efficient query for getting each agent's earliest quarter and the sales for that quarter?

It's easy to find out "What is each agent's first quarter?":

```
SELECT agent, min(quarter) FROM salestable GROUP BY agent
```

But this doesn't include the sales figures, so I thought I'd do a join:

```
SELECT agent, sales
FROM salestable s1
JOIN
(
   SELECT agent AS e, MIN(quarter) AS q
   FROM salestable
   GROUP by employee
) AS q1 ON q1.e=s1.agent AND q1.mq=s1.quarter
```

But this is unacceptably slow on my data set. If I could use a cursor, it would only take one pass through the table, but using a query it seems to require a join. Is that right?

Comment: Your query looks good... I don't think a cursor would improve anything... what indexes do you have on your `salestable`?

Comment: Do you have an `(Agent, Quarter)` index?

Comment: Pretty sure the index is (Agent,Quarter). Using a cursor makes the query instantaneous. Using the query I posted takes 10 minutes. ???

Comment: Could this be a view instead of a table you're querying?

Answer (score 6):

Try this variation and see if it's any better:

```
WITH cteRowNum AS (
    SELECT agent, quarter, sales,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY agent ORDER BY quarter) AS RowNum
        FROM salestable
)
SELECT agent, quarter, sales
    FROM cteRowNum
    WHERE RowNum = 1;
```